# Can I use the confidence ratings for the intents in creating the flow for the Watson Conversation API flow?

Tags: watson-conversation

Can I use the confidence ratings for the intents in the conditions for the nodes in the dialog flow in the Watson Conversation API ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this create a condition that looks for your intent, and then checks the confidence.

Sample condition you would have

```
#temperature
AND
intents[0].confidence > 0.70
```

In the UI, it can be tricky to type this. So for the first part select the intent from your drop down as you type. For the second part, after you type it then click on the "Create new condition" in the drop down. It will stop it being erased.

In the output text field you can also add:

```
<? intents ?>
```

This will display in your test chat window the Intent JSON blob. So you can use this to see if it is working.